# Different read_csv index_col = None / 0 / False in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I used the read_csv command following below:

```
    In [20]:
    dataframe = pd.read_csv('D:/UserInterest/output/ENFP_0719/Bookmark.csv', index_col=None)
    dataframe.head()
    Out[20]:
    Unnamed: 0  timestamp   url visits
    0   0   1.404028e+09    http://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=mi...   2
    1   1   1.404028e+09    http://m.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fblo...   1
    2   2   1.404028e+09    market://details?id=com.kakao.story 1
    3   3   1.404028e+09    https://story-api.kakao.com/upgrade/install 4
    4   4   1.403889e+09    http://m.cafe.daum.net/WorldcupLove/Knj/173424...   1
```

The result shows column `Unnamed:0` and it is simillar when I used `index_col=False`, but when I used `index_col=0`, the result is following below:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('D:/UserInterest/output/ENFP_0719/Bookmark.csv', index_col=0)
dataframe.head()
Out[21]:
timestamp   url visits
0   1.404028e+09    http://m.blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=mi...   2
1   1.404028e+09    http://m.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fblo...   1
2   1.404028e+09    market://details?id=com.kakao.story 1
3   1.404028e+09    https://story-api.kakao.com/upgrade/install 4
4   1.403889e+09    http://m.cafe.daum.net/WorldcupLove/Knj/173424...   1
```

The result did show the column `Unnamed:0`, In here I want to ask, what is the difference between `index_col=None`, `index_col=0`, and `index_col=False`, I have read the documentation in [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), but I still did not get the idea.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think since version [0.16.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.16.1.html) it will now raise an error if you try to pass `True` for `index_col` to avoid this ambiguity

**ORIGINAL**

A lot of people get confused by this, to specify the ordinal index of your column you should pass the int position in this case `0`.

```
In [3]:

import io
import pandas as pd
t="""index,a,b
0,hello,pandas"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
​
Out[3]:
   index      a       b
0      0  hello  pandas
```

The default value is `index_col=None` as shown above.

If we set `index_col=0` we're explicitly stating to treat the first column as the index:

```
In [4]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=0)
Out[4]:
           a       b
index               
0      hello  pandas
```

If we pass `index_col=False` we get the same result as `None`:

```
In [5]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=False)
Out[5]:
   index      a       b
0      0  hello  pandas
```

If we now state `index_col=None` we get the same behaviour as when we didn't pass this param:

```
In [6]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=None)
Out[6]:
   index      a       b
0      0  hello  pandas
```

There is a bug where if you pass `True` this was erroneously being converted to `index_col=1` as `True` was being converted to `1`:

```
In [6]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=True)
Out[6]:
       index       b
a               
0      hello  pandas
```

**EDIT**

For the case where you have a blank index column which is what you have:

```
In [7]:

import io
import pandas as pd
t=""",a,b
0,hello,pandas"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
​
Out[7]:
   Unnamed: 0      a       b
0           0  hello  pandas
In [8]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=0)
Out[8]:
       a       b
0  hello  pandas
In [9]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=False)
Out[9]:
   Unnamed: 0      a       b
0           0  hello  pandas
In [10]:

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=None)
Out[10]:
   Unnamed: 0      a       b
0           0  hello  pandas
```