# Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to read 'year' and 'month' from a csv to put them into a single column.
i can do this without `index_col` or with `index_col=1` or more.
but when i try `index_col=0` i get an error:

`Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)`

this is my csv file:

```
No,year,month,gw,temp,evap
1,2010,1,120.92,66.695,54.62
2,2010,2,121.11,67.15,54.62
3,2010,3,121.2,67.11,54.22
4,2010,4,119.33,67.495,53.12
```

This is my code:

```
def parse(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m').strftime('%Y %m')
dataset = read_csv('data_test1.csv', parse_dates=[['year', 'month']], index_col=0 ,date_parser=parse)
dataset.drop('No', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

and this is my `dataset.head()` after i execute the above code:

| datetime | No | gw | temp | evap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 01 | 1 | 120.92 | 66.695 | 54.62 |
| 2010 02 | 2 | 121.11 | 67.150 | 54.62 |
| 2010 03 | 3 | 121.20 | 67.110 | 54.22 |
| 2010 04 | 4 | 119.33 | 67.495 | 53.12 |
| 2010 05 | 5 | 119.26 | 67.280 | 53.30 |

i want to have it like this:

```
              gw      temp    evap
date                                                                 
2010-01-01    120.92  66.695  54.62
2010-01-01    121.11  67.150  54.62
2010-01-01    121.20  67.110  54.22
2010-01-01    119.33  67.495  53.12
2010-01-01    119.26  67.280  53.30
```

the code below i run:

```
import pandas as pd

def parse(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y %m')

dfT = pd.read_csv('data_test1.csv')
dfT['datetime']= dfT['datetime'].apply(parse)
dfT['year'], dfT['month'] = dfT['datetime'].dt.year, dfT['datetime'].dt.month
dfT.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkul8.png)

i insist on having the date with year-month format to use them on my graphs.
if anyone can help
<3

Comment: hello can you add a minimal reproducible example of the dataframe pls? df = pd.DataFrame({.. }) and one with expected outcome :>

Comment: What are you planning to do with index_col = 0? Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862864/different-read-csv-index-col-none-0-false-in-pandas

Comment: suggest to read the csv to df, *then* combine year & month column and parse to datetime. also note that `datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m').strftime('%Y %m')` effectively does nothing: it parses a string to datetime only to format to string again in same format.

Comment: @JasonChia im trying to have the datetime as my index. but when set `index_col=0` i  get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset and the output you are looking for does not match, still I believe that the best approach would do the following

```
import pandas as pd

def parse(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y %m')

dfT = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dfT['datetime1']= dfT['datetime'].apply(parse)
dfT['year'], dfT['month'], dfT['month_name'] = dfT['datetime1'].dt.year, dfT['datetime1'].dt.month, dfT['datetime1'].dt.month_name()
dfT.set_index('datetime1', inplace=True)
dfT.drop('No', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I don't know if you are looking to do it with several datasets, and you need to automatize the process. Your question was not very clear to be honest, still I believe that will solver your current problem. I would advice you create a function to pass only the dataframe, and if you have several you can use a list comprehension while using the function.

Comment: my original csv file has no datetime column. its like what i wrote at the end of the post. it has `year` and `month` column

Comment: @Betabore did you even try what I sent to you before being argumentative when someone is trying to help you? Plus I mentioned the output wanted, I got the part about the date

Comment: my dear i do not argue. first thanks for your time spending here both on my question and solving it. yes i tried it. i get an error again since in this line `dfT['datetime']= dfT['datetime'].apply(parse)` we want to read the datetime column and there is no datetime column yet

Comment: @Betabore I am a bit confused as you marked the answer as correct. the function parse will turn your string column into a datetime column. I ran it here before and it worked for me.

Comment: `KeyError: 'datetime'` im geting a key error when i run the code

Comment: @Betabore copy the answer again as I have changed it there, you should not get this message at all, but anyhow there is a way around.

Comment: Unfortunately same error :(

Comment: It is odd to say the least, I ran this code and worked fine. Could you past your code in a comment please?

Comment: i paste exactly what you wrote up here but i just changed the csv file name

Comment: i'v updated my question with an image in it if you can check it please

Comment: KeyError: 'datetime' is related to a column, load the df first and check the name of the columns you have, perhaps the datetime has a different name in your .csv file, if so replace for related name.

Comment: my columns names are this in my csv file : No,year,month,gw,temp,evap

Comment: thanks bro. i used my own code but i used the line you wrote: `dataset.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)` instead of `index_col=0` and its good now. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

with the help of @ReinholdN i fixed the problem and this is the final code:

```
def parse(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m').strftime('%Y %m')
dataset = read_csv('data_test1.csv', parse_dates={'datetime': ['year', 'month']}, date_parser=parse)
dataset.drop('No', axis=1, inplace=True)
dataset.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

The last line `dataset.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)` is like i say `index_col=0`